# Search and retrieve records from a number of Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a number of Google spreadsheets, and each spreadsheet contains a number of records (rows). Let's say something like this:

[Example spreadsheet with some records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEhTW.png)

I would like to have a new spreadsheet for searching and retrieving the records, based on the parameters defined at the top, like here:

[Example spreadsheet for searching and retrieving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD0HY.png)

Is it possible to do this with Google Spreadsheets? Please let me know if you have an idea how to do this.

Thanks!

Piotr

Answer (score 1):

There is [Google Spread Sheet formula](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en). Check for more.

[Check this link](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-filter-function/), for your question.

Next time showing any effort, what did you tried or something link which is relevant to the question.